# Best approach for assigning user roles for different groups in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Here are the basic models without roles:

group model

```
    class Group < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :users, through :memberships
    end
```

user model

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :groups, through :memberships
    end
```

memberships model

```
    class Membership < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :group
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

Each group should have 1 (and only one) `owner`, multiple `admins` (assigned by the owner), and the rest `general` members. Also, the ownership role needs to be *transferable*. My options, as I see them:

1. Create a single attribute `role` on the membership table and assign it a string value of "owner", "manager", or "general". [bad]
2. Create multiple booleans for "owner", "manager", and "general" on the membership table. [bad]
3. Create a `Role` model/table with 1 column ("name") and 3 rows ("owner", "manager", "general") then update my models like so:

Role model

```
    class Role < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :users, through :memberships
      has_many :groups, through :memberships
    end
```

group model

```
    class Group < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :users, through :memberships
      has_many :roles, through :memberships
    end
```

user model

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :groups, through :memberships
      has_many :roles, through :memberships
    end
```

memberships model

```
    class Membership < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :group
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :role
    end
```

4. Create separate arrays for the various roles directly on the group model. This seems really stupid, as updating a role would require the pushing and splicing of multiple arrays, and I would have to concatenate multiple arrays to present a simple list of memberships.

group model

```
    class Group < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :general_memberships, class_name: 'Membership'
      has_many :admin_memberships, class_name: 'Membership'
      has_one :owner_membership, class_name: 'Membership'

      has_many :users, through :memberships
    end
```

user model

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :general_memberships, class_name: 'Membership'
      has_many :admin_memberships, class_name: 'Membership'
      has_many :owner_memberships, class_name: 'Membership'

      has_many :groups, through :memberships
    end
```

memberships model

```
    class Membership < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :group
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

I know there are gems out there like CanCanCan (Rails 5 compatible?) and Groupify, but I want to understand all my options first. I think option #3 is probably my best best, at least without without utilizing a gem. Wondering what the community considers best practice for my scenario.

Comment: found anything?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I ended up going with the following solution and have been very satisfied with it in a production app. Since a group can only have one owner, it made since to use a belongs_to relationship for that role.

For the Membership model, I took advantage of active record enum. Since the enum array only holds two values, it actually would have been more efficient to simply add a "manager" boolean to the membership model. True means manager, false means general. But I went with the enum approach, because I anticipate needing additional roles in the near future, and using enum they will be VERY easy to add.

group model

```
    class Group < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :users, through :memberships
    end
```

user model

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :owned_groups, class_name: 'Group', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
      has_many :memberships
      has_many :groups, through :memberships
    end
```

membership model

```
    class Membership < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :group
      belongs_to :user

      enum role: [:general, :manager]
    end
```

Comment: Well, sounds good, its your question, and your solution, amke this ccepted answer (Y)

Comment: This oughta be a Rails 5 gem.